# Stop an Infinite Loop in Python While Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm working on a simple python program that involves creating a circle "button" and then having the user click within the circle. If they don't click on the circle, a message comes up stating that they have clicked outside of the circle and should try again. However, on the last part I'm getting an endless loop on the code, despite using a break. Is there any way anyone could help see if there is an error? Thanks!

```
r = 75

while True:
    # to determine if click is within circle
    length = math.sqrt(((x-100)**2) +((y-250)**2)) 
    if length == r or length < r: 
        break 
    # prints if user does not click within the range
    print("Please click within the spin button")
```

Comment: The code is working fine for me when I use a numerical value of length, see if the x and y co-ordinates you get are correct and the formula you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` are never updated within the `while` loop, so if they are outside of your circle in the first iteration, `length` will always remain at the same value (bigger than `r`), and the `break` statement will never be executed.

Also, use `if length >= r:`. No need to check the two conditions separately. (Logically, it should be `if length > r:` anyway since a click on the edge of the circle should still count.)

Comment: Pietcker: How could we break the infinite loop while it's taking place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to clicks, you are usually using some kind of GUI framework, TKinter, GTK, QT, wx something similar or a wrapper around that lie PythonCard. With is you can connect an event, like a click on an element to a method, which should contain your code. This way the code is not run in a loop but only when the click happens.
The actual code depends a lot on the GUI framework you choose, but you did not give any information on that.

Comment: How to stop an infinite loop as it happens? I've tried Ctrl +Alt+ Delete within Windows, but it did not save my work.

Answer (score -1):

```
r = 75
while True:
    # to determine if click is within circle
    length = math.sqrt(((x-100)**2) +((y-250)**2)) 
    if length == r or length < r: 
        break 
    else:
    # prints if user does not click within the range
    print("Please click within the spin button")
```

Your code is correct just needs else statement. else statement runs when if statement is false.
so here suppose if statement is correct then the code would break, but when if statement is false, the code would go to else statement and would print Please click within the spin button.

Thank You.